# Use Git / Github to sync my Projects between PC / Laptop / WebInterface

Tags: git, bash, synchronization

I'm really new at GIT. My aim is to sync my Eclipse Projects between PC / Laptop - and I thought it would be a good Idea to use GIT for this.
So I've set up my Repository, got it into Github, etc.

I have written a small Bash-Script which should do the sync work for me. It seems to work, but I'm not sure this is the best way to do:

```
#!/bin/bash          
# Github Syncro Script

# SoftwareProjekte
cd "D:\Projekte\Software Projekte"
git add . 
git commit -a -m "Auto-Git-Backup $(date "+%d.%m.%Y %H:%M "|sed -e ' s/\"/\\\"/g' )"
git push -u origin master
git pull
```

Is this a good Idea? Should I use something like http://code.google.com/p/git-sync/ instead?
What bugs me about this script is that I have to enter my Password two times.

Comment: I think git add . is redundant if you are using -a in your commit statement

Comment: Easiest way to avoid the passwords, is to use an SSH key, and a ssh-agent to keep it in.

Comment: @Douglas: How does this work?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how git interacts with ssh agents on Windows. You might have to experiment with putty's agent, or cygwin's ssh-agent to see if either of them can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use scripts like this to work with git, it's nice because you can develop your custom script  as you learn more features, there are other tools out there but it justy comes down to personal preference.

One thing I would say, to sync from git it's as simple as

```
git pull
```

If you are commiting to git first you should be doing a pull to reduce the risk of the local copy being an old version and creating conflicts.

Something like this:

```
cd "D:\Projekte\Software Projekte"
git pull
git add . 
git commit -a -m "Auto-Git-Backup $(date "+%d.%m.%Y %H:%M "|sed -e ' s/\"/\\\"/g' )"
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: This means, I shouldn't commit anything first, but just use git pull?

Comment: Git pull doesn't commit anything to my remote Repo. So it's just to get the latest state which I had already commited by my other devices?

Comment: Your right git pull doesn't commit, but your script is commiting to repo which may have been updated by other device, you are best pulling in those changes to check everything is up-to-date before commiting

Comment: Ok, thanks! This is a good hint!

Another question: I still have to enter my Password 2-3 times for this one script. Is there a way to make this smarter?

Comment: I may be wrong but I think if you generate a SSH key that doesn't require a password then you shouldn't get this request, I don't get it

Comment: Tryed around now a bit and GIT tells me I cant do git pull until i've commited my local Changes first. 

So it looks like it is pull after commit and push?

Comment: If you have a problem with pulling it means you local changes are conflicting with up stream changes. In this case you need to do a stash, which stores your local working tree moves you back to the last commit, does a pull, you can then so git stash pop to get you local changes back, at which point you can commit

Comment: If you tried pushing before doing this I think you will find yourself in a mess where your commits agains the old state of the repo will attempted to be pushed into a new code base, possible wiping over newer changes

Comment: @whatsthebeef: Didn't know about git-stash! This is something i was looking for but didn't know that its an actual Feature :) Thanks!

Looks like I'm getting to know GIT a little better ;)

Comment: @Simon you need to check out this site: http://gitimmersion.com/index.html it's the best resource I have found for beginning with git

Comment: Yes, i've already found that site - really nice beginner tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

Now I think i've learned a bit about GIT and my new Syncro-Script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash          
# Github Syncro Script

git pull
git add --all
git commit -m "Auto-Git-Backup $(date "+%d.%m.%Y %H:%M "|sed -e ' s/\"/\\\"/g' )"
git push -u origin master
```

`git add --all` seems better than `commit -a` because it adds new files and also removes deleted files.

It also looks like that I have to pull (and merge my remote changes with my own) before I can push my local changes. (In Case of Conflict)

Is this correct?

By the way: This article / graphic helped me a lot to understand how GIT Repositorys work:
http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/21/pushing-and-pulling.html